# CompletableFuture.runAsync Swallowing Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

Good morning,

I'm not quite getting the hang of CompletableFutures (I am an experienced developer, but I am not finding them particularly intuitive!).

Given the following snippet:

```
public CompletionStage<Void> leaveGame(GameService gameService)
{
  return gameService.deregister(playerName)
                    .exceptionally(t -> {
                      LOGGER.info("Could not deregister: {}", t.getMessage());
                      throw new CompletionException(t);
                    });
}
```

which is called by the unit test:

```
@Test
public void shouldCompleteExceptionallyForFailedLeave()
{
  var failFlow = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
  failFlow.completeExceptionally(new Exception("TestNonExistentPlayer"));
  when(mockedGameService.deregister(any(String.class))).thenReturn(failFlow);

  try
  {
    player.leaveGame(mockedGameService).toCompletableFuture().get();
    fail("Exception should have been thrown");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    assertEquals(Exception.class, e.getCause().getClass());
  }
  verify(mockedGameService, times(1)).deregister(any(String.class));
}
```

which mocks `gameService.deregister(...)` to completeExceptionally and return `Exception`.

In the above case, as expected, the exceptionally branch is triggered, the message is logged, and the exception in the unit test is caught, i.e. the `fail(...)` assertion is not triggered.

However, when I want to run a CompletionStage before leave game, e.g.:

```
public CompletionStage<Void> leaveGame(GameService gameService)
{
  return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("BLAH"))
                          .thenRun(() -> gameService.deregister(playerName)
                                                    .exceptionally(t -> {
                                                      LOGGER.info("Could not deregister: {}", t.getMessage());
                                                      throw new CompletionException(t);
                                                    }));
}
```

The exceptionally branch **is** still triggered, but the exception is now not caught by the test method, i.e. the `fail(...)` assertion **is** triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original definition

```
public CompletionStage<Void> leaveGame(GameService gameService)
{
  return gameService.deregister(playerName)
                    .exceptionally(t -> {
                      LOGGER.info("Could not deregister: {}", t.getMessage());
                      throw new CompletionException(t);
                    });
}
```

The method `leaveGame` did not throw an exception but always returned a future. The caller has to examine the future to find out whether the encapsulated operation has failed.

Likewise when you move the same code into a `Runnable` like

```
public CompletionStage<Void> leaveGame(GameService gameService)
{
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("BLAH"))
        .thenRun(() -> gameService.deregister(playerName)
                                  .exceptionally(t -> {
                                    LOGGER.info("Could not deregister: {}", t.getMessage());
                                    throw new CompletionException(t);
                                  }));
}
```

The `Runnable` will not throw an exception. It’s still required to examine the future returned by `gameService.deregister(…).exceptionally(…)` to find out whether it failed, but now, you are not returning it but just dropping the reference.

To create a future whose completion depends on a future returned by a function evaluation, you need [`thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-):

```
public CompletionStage<Void> leaveGame(GameService gameService)
{
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("BLAH"))
        .thenCompose(voidArg -> gameService.deregister(playerName)
                                  .exceptionally(t -> {
                                    LOGGER.info("Could not deregister: {}", t.getMessage());
                                    throw new CompletionException(t);
                                  }));
}
```

So now you’re implementing a `Function<Void,CompletionStage<Void>>` rather than `Runnable` and the stage returned by the function will be use to complete the future returned by `leaveGame`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, Holger. You've helped me get my head around the fact that `leaveGame` did not throw an exception, rather an `ExecutionException` was thrown when `get()` was called on the CF, the `exceptionally()` stage of which aborted by throwing an exception. And, of course, Runnable.run() returns void!